# Angular 8 Unable to access images in assets folder

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I'm unable to access the images available in the assets folder:

```
src
 |->app
 |->assets
    |->images
        |->image1.jpg
        |->image2.png
```

in app.component.html

```
src
 |->app
     |-> app.component.html
```

I'm trying to use these images

`<img src="../assets/images/image1.jpg"/>`
`<img src="../assets/images/image2.png"/>`

Even I have added this in angular.json

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/images/image1.jpg",
              "src/assets/images/image2.png"
            ],
```

images are showing like this:

[image]

Please let me how to fix it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: directly use `/assets/images/image1.jpg`

Comment: And also in the `assets` array you can just type `src/assets/`

Comment: @Rohit.007  I got this error: {"The controller for path '/assets/images/image1.jpg' was not found or does not implement IController."} System.Web.HttpException

Comment: try accessing the image directly on browser. e.g. `http://localhost:4200/assets/images/image1.jpg` and make sure the path and the image name is correct

Comment: and remove these `              "src/assets/images/image1.jpg",
              "src/assets/images/image2.png"` from `angular.json`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<img src="/assets/images/image1.jpg"/> <img src="/assets/images/image2.png"/>`

Comment: I got the same error: {"The controller for path '/assets/images/image1.jpg' was not found or does not implement IController."} System.Web.HttpException

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<img src="assets/images/image1.jpg"/> <img src="assets/images/image2.png"/>
```

Comment: It will not load the image if you are in the child route. then it will concat the base url before the assets url